# The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I want to retrieve data from Firestore to be displayed in my application, but if I run my application, I get an error like this :

*The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:*

This happens when I use 'data [' first name], and also 'data [saldo]. toString (), on child Text ();

I don't know what should I do to solve this problem

my code is below :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Top extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TopState createState() => _TopState();
}

class _TopState extends State<Top> {
  dynamic data;

  Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    final DocumentReference document = Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document('Ljlhq1wqPad4EejHTHPqIyGjJSD2');

    await document.get().then<dynamic>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
      setState(() {
        data = snapshot.data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Color(0xff216353),
              height: 170,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //Row utama
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 20),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  data['firstname'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65.0, left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    'Total Saldo : ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65.0, left: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    data['saldo'].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filling your data with a Future method called `getData()`.

The error is probably because when the `build` method renders your screen, the data is still null. Your method `getData()` take some time to finish.

You can work with FutureBuilder to solve this situation:
Read this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you know that you get this error because data is null.

I cant see errors in your code so I think the value comes null from database. Can you check snapshot.data value?

```
setState(() {
  data = snapshot.data;
});
```

Thank you